# Mutt: move emails only if some emails are tagged

Tags: mutt, macro

I use `mutt` and I like to sort out some emails from various mailing lists. I still like them to come to my inbox, but when read, I want to move them somehow automatically.

Currently, I do the following:

- Select the mails matching a pattern, e.g.: `T~f facebook.com`
- Move them to some place: `;s=Facebook`

I made some macros to avoid typing it by myself. However I still need to do the two separate steps. And considering that I have a few different mailing lists (say, LinkedIn as well), that's two steps for each list.

I would like to reduce it in a single step, that is to say **one command (macro) to select a few messages based on the pattern and move them.**

The problem is that `;s` does not check if some mails are already tagged. So that if none are tagged, it will move the current mail. How could I add some condition to `;s` to do nothing if no tag is set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not a mutt user, but it looks like `tag-prefix-cond` can do this. It is like `tag-prefix` but *if there aren't any tagged
messages, the command buffer is flushed without doing anything (in
other words, whatever hook you're in stops dead in its tracks)*, from this [mutt-users@mutt.org](http://narkive.com/FFzgaXlm:2.870.157) archive.